# WordPress Ajax logic

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a problem with Ajax in WordPress.

Lets say I have an Ajax script that loads `.php` script. I have `$_REQUEST['id']` (that's WordPress post id) in that script and that's all.

I can write custom loop and get pages/posts. That's not a problem.

But I need to load WordPress core, hierarchy system like a normal page. I have a lot of custom code that depends on `$post->ID` in `page.php`.

So I need to pass id variable from Ajax script and load `page.php` or `single.php`.

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add this to your php file

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('../../../wp-load.php');
?>
```

Comment: You are adding all the wordpress headers etc. so this will allow you to add the wordpress codex shortcuts to your php (e.g. `the_title;`) file that isnt part of the theme

Comment: Thanks, but now what about the `$_REQUEST['id']` . I have wordpress functions but not `page.php` or `single.php` template. I need `$_REQUEST['id']` to be the same as `$post->ID`

Comment: what about using `$_GET['page_id'];`

Comment: I think that will work, i still have to rebuild page.php, remove header and footer and thats it. Thanks man :)

Comment: `wp-load.php` didnt work. I had to include `wp-blog-header.php` instead. not sure exactly why but it works